# Placing a text below an image

Tags: html, css

I want to place the text below the image.But when i add a paragraph, it is set  behind the image. How to fix this please ???

```html
<div style="width:96%;"><img src="../Images/2.jpg" height="640" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 1200px; height: 700px; float: left; z-index: 0;"/></div>

<div><p>Vision defines the optimal desired future state and the conceptual image of what an organization wants to achieve over time. It provides guidance and inspiration to what an organization is focused on achieving in some time. It is written briefly in an inspirational manner that makes it easy for all employees to repeat it at any given time. “All Sri Lankans seamlessly connected with world-class information, communication and entertainment services" is the vision of SLT.</p><</div>
```

Comment: `<</div>` what's that? you mean `&lt;</div>`?

Comment: I got wrong that. Only </div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You positioned the picture absolute, thats why it is in a layer above the text.
simply drop the style and the text follows vertically after the block element `div`.

```css
body{
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:96%;">
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/0nJG7lN.png" />
</div>

<p>Vision defines the optimal desired future state and the conceptual image of what an organization wants to achieve over time. It provides guidance and inspiration to what an organization is focused on achieving in some time. It is written briefly in an inspirational manner that makes it easy for all employees to repeat it at any given time. “All Sri Lankans seamlessly connected with world-class information, communication and entertainment services" is the vision of SLT.</p>
```

Comment: I positioned the image as absolute ,because i want to align it left edge of the iframe. If i remove the absolute, the image doesnot align to corner.

Comment: that was not part of the question ;) but I added a tiny css to remove the margin.

Answer (score 1):

Since the DIV is positioned `absolute`
place the `<p>` tag **inside that DIV** right after the `<img>` tag.
Hope it will work.

Comment: It worked. But the image doesn't align to the corner of the iframe. It shows a little gap.